# How to Enhance social office theme for Liferay

Tags: liferay-theme

I would like to enhance the social office theme for liferay : so-theme.

I tried to create a new theme with the liferay IDE but the default theme is still used.

Has anyone modified the social office theme?

Thanks a lot for yours answers

Comment: There is no real question here. http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: Can you show us what you tried to do ? Where exactly did you have a problem ? You said you created a new theme from so-theme, did you set your site to use the new theme ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the answer on the [liferay forum](http://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/view_message/4149091#_19_message_4147358), answer from [Liferay staff](http://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/view_message/4149091#_19_message_4149091):

> Unfortunately, changing so-theme is the only way to do it. We locked down the ability to deploy a theme because the majority of (most likely all) of the portal themes would be incompatible with the way we do a few things in SO.

[**Suggestion**](http://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/view_message/4149091#_19_message_4265045) in the same forum post by Liferay Staff:

> My suggestion for now would be to add another "include" line in the main.css at the very end and keep your changes there. I think this will make maintainability easier for you until we find a permanent solution for theming Social Office.

So it's not possible to create a new liferay theme based on `so-theme`. The only way is to directly modify the deploy theme.