# Is it possible to override Social Office theme in Liferay 6.1?

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, liferay-theme

I would like to override Social Office theme (so-theme) in Liferay 6.1.20 EE, because I would like to use its layout and social office experience, but with some changes in css, page templates, etc.

I've already seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13063373/how-to-enhance-social-office-theme-for-liferay)
but it is concluded that there is no way to do it, except from editing the actual so-theme, which development-wise and upgrade-wise is obviously problematic.

I've tried copying the whole so-theme with its jars to a new theme project, so that I could have a diff folder with my changes, but I did not manage to make it work.

I have made the proper changes (plugin name etc) in properties files and after I deploy it, I can see my new theme (w/o icon though) but when I select it, the following exception is thrown:

```
09:37:23,043 INFO  [com.liferay.portal.plugin.PluginPackageUtil][PluginPackageUtil:1465] Finished checking for available updates in 1125 ms
Exception in thread "http-bio-9091-exec-4" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.util.HashMap.getEntry(HashMap.java:344)
    at java.util.HashMap.containsKey(HashMap.java:335)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.setAttribute(Request.java:1512)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.setAttribute(RequestFacade.java:542)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilter.doFilter(InvokerFilter.java:62)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:108)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilter.doFilter(InvokerFilter.java:73)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:206)
```

Is it possible to manage it somehow? Maybe with some additional configuration's in my theme's properties files? I can provide more code if needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to access so-theme in a development-friendly way is to just [use the source](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-plugins/tree/master/themes/so-theme). (Choose the proper tag/branch). Should be easier than manually creating the _diffs folder. Please try with this and report back if it does not help

Comment: It worked fine! I followed these steps:

1. Using Liferay Developer Studio, I created a new Liferay Theme Project, with the name 'so-theme' (-theme suffix is added automatically)
2. I downloaded the so-theme source from the git link you provided
3. I replaced the contents of the project's docroot folder with those of the downloaded project's docroot folder
4. I deleted previously deployed so-theme from my tomcat (from webapps and work folder) - do not know if this was actually needed for sure
5. I deployed my new theme project to tomcat and started it
6. It worked fine!